# Coldfusion Ajax Multi-File Upload - CFFile Overwriting ServerFile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I've taken some code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145805/upload-multiple-files-with-jquery-and-coldfusion-cffile) for the multi-file upload, which works fine but the `cffile` overwrites the `cffile.serverFile` so in the `parm` dump the only file name I get is the last one it uploaded, not all of them.

I tried looping it, appending an array each time, but still the same problem. It seems `cffile` is uploading all files selected in one go. In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145805/upload-multiple-files-with-jquery-and-coldfusion-cffile) the OP said he made a JSON response with the correct data but I have no idea how to do that since I can't get all the names back anyway.

**Caller:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#multiFileFrm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.each($('#multiFile')[0].files, function(i, file) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('file-0', file);
                ajaxUpload(formData);
            });
        });
        function ajaxUpload(formData) {
            console.log("ajaxUpload function called");
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "ajax/AJAX_multiUploadTest.cfm",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#callback').html(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="multiFileFrm">
    <input type="file" name="multiFile" id="multiFile" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitFrm" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="callback"></div>
```

**AJAX_multiUploadTest.cfm:**

```
<cftry>
<cfobject component="code/profile" name="pro">
<cfset parm={}>
<cfset parm.userID=session.visitor.user.ID>
<cfset parm.database=application.datasource>
<cfset parm.form=form>

<cfset path="#application.directory#/data/dev/">
<cfif NOT DirectoryExists(path)><cfdirectory action="create" directory="#path#"></cfif>

<cffile action="upload" filefield="file-0" destination="#path#" nameConflict="makeUnique">
<cfset upload="#application.directory#/data/dev/#cffile.serverfile#">

<cfdump var="#parm#" label="parm" expand="no">
<cfcatch type="any">
    <cfdump var="#cfcatch#" label="cfcatch" expand="no">
</cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

Comment: What version of ColdFusion?

Answer (score 3):

Wow, by reading my own post I have figured out the problem. The callback file gets called in a loop from the JavaScript, so each time it overwrites the variables. In order to store all file names, I just simply stored them in a session variable:

```
<cfset arrayAppend(session.visitor.user.tempData, "#application.domain#data/dev/#cffile.serverfile#")>
```

This then outputs all files uploaded and once processed by other functions, maybe to store it in the database, you can just empty the array!

Hope this helps someone :)